# Fetch in react always return (Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch

Consider the Fetch request (React) :

```
fetch(
  "Some url ...",
  {
    method: `GET`,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  }
).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    });
  }
});
```

When executing the Fetching I always get :

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at
>   position 0

Any idea how to fix this ? I can't get the data from the response.

Comment: If your code is running in a browser, you can use the "Network" developer tab to look at the response body.

Comment: Apparently the server doesn't give you JSON. Probably it answers something like «Request is invalid». It usually happens due to API misuse or when the server is down. 

To make sure, try to open "Some url ..." in your browser.

Comment: @AntonRusak ` Accept: "application/json"` implies that the response will be a json. also the `.json` is used with the check `response.ok` which return true only when the status is 200s.

Comment: @AZ_ you re totally right. Though we know nothing'bout the server. It may return some crap with status 200 effectively ignoring the Accept header.

Comment: @AntonRusak: I checked the response of the server from Chrome , and it returns a response : `ResponseCode=0&Description=OK&url=https%3a%2f%2f-big-url-etc-etc-etc`

Comment: @JAN Thas is not JSON. You tell the browser to parse the body of the response as JSON. It tells you that is not JSON. Maybe you should use response.text() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AntonRusak , the problem was `json` instead of `text`:

```
 fetch(
      "Your-url",
      {
        method: `GET`,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/text"
        }
      }
    ).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.text().then(text=> {
          console.log(text);
        });
      }
    });
```